# Unmarshalling data into any struct

Tags: go

When Unmarshalling data from an endpoint, I almost always have a struct with the data that I am want to get from my request that I unmarshal into. Well there are times where I want to see everything that is returning back to me but I am not sure what some of that data is so I don't know how to define it in my struct. Is there a way to have a struct that can just grab all data being unmarshalled without me having to specify it?

This is what I thought would work but that is not the case

```
resp, err := httpClient.Get("/api/stuff")
data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

var myStruct struct{}
json.Unmarshal(data, myStruct)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not know the composition of a JSON object in advance, [you can unmarshal into a `map[string]interface{}`.](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal)

```
var myMap map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(data, &myMap)
```

See an example [here.](https://play.golang.org/p/zSDbnYq_gv)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to define your struct, then maybe you should [use a map.](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action)  It's a pretty good fit for unmarshalling JSON.  Here is an example of how to do it without knowing exactly what data you are receiving:

```
func parseJSON(r *http.Request) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    var postData interface{}
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    err := decoder.Decode(&postData)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return postData.(map[string]interface{}), nil
}
```

Now you at least have a string name of each piece of data, which should give your application some idea of how to handle it.